# bindAttr and registerBoundHelper together

Tags: ember.js

Is it possible to use a registerBoundHelper when changing the value of an attribute using bindAttr?
**HTML**

```
<div class="bar" {{styleWidth bindAttr style="value"}}></div>
```

**JS**

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('styleWidth', function(width){
    return ("width: " + width + "px;");
});
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a bound helper that observes the style is hard to implement.

There is a `Ember.StyleBindingsMixin` in [emberella](https://github.com/realityendshere/emberella) that handle this for you.

I hope it helps

Comment: I am personally only concerned with one-direction (model to view) data binding. I may have to define a helper method on the view such as in this example I found: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/tomwhatmore/rearT/3/)